Proportion after performing k-means clustering
I have 22 columns and need to do k-means clustering (k=5) for selected labels which are gender, education, age, years of marriage and amount spent. After doing k-means clustering, I am require to determine the number of samples and the calculate the number of 0 and 1 (using another column named test). I need to use the cluster column and take out the test to calculate the proportion of 0 and 1.
Sample of the data

set_1 = ['GENDER', 'EDUCATION', 'AGE', 'MARRIAGE', 'AMOUNT_SPENT']
df_1 = df[set_1]
K = 5
random_seed = 1

model = KMeans(n_clusters=K, random_state=random_seed)

model.fit(data_norm1)

df1_norm = pd.DataFrame(data_norm1, columns=df_1.columns)

cluster_labels = model.labels_
df1_norm['Cluster1'] = cluster_labels

df1_norm

cluster_counts = df1_norm.groupby('Cluster1').size()
print(cluster_counts)

I managed to calculate the number of sample but unable to group into 0 and 1 at each cluster. At the earlier part of the code (before clustering), I have group the full set of data into 0 and 1. I tried to use groupby() to link the two sets of data.
grp1 = df1_norm.groupby(['GENDER', 'EDUCATION', 'AGE', 'MARRIAGE', 'AMOUNT_SPENT', 'TEST'])

Error message is KeyError: 'DEFAULT'.
Can someone point out the error for me?
Expected output will be something like that
Cluster       No. of positive
0     9095    8098
1     6933    2345
2     11685   7892  
3     7190    2345
4     5097    2342
dtype: int64

Your expected output is useless with a sample of the original data.

Your question lack any sample data, so I created a dataframe of my own. What you are looking for can be achieved this way:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

np.random.seed(1)
data = {
    'GENDER': np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], 100),
    'EDUCATION': np.random.choice(['High School', 'Bachelor', 'Master', 'PhD'], 100),
    'AGE': np.random.randint(18, 60, 100),
    'MARRIAGE': np.random.randint(1, 30, 100),
    'AMOUNT_SPENT': np.random.randint(100, 10000, 100),
    'DEFAULT': np.random.choice([0, 1], 100)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['GENDER'] = df['GENDER'].map({'Male': 0, 'Female': 1})
df['EDUCATION'] = df['EDUCATION'].map({'High School': 0, 'Bachelor': 1, 'Master': 2, 'PhD': 3})

features = ['GENDER', 'EDUCATION', 'AGE', 'MARRIAGE', 'AMOUNT_SPENT']
X = df[features]

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

K = 5
random_seed = 1

model = KMeans(n_clusters=K, random_state=random_seed)
model.fit(X_scaled)

df['Cluster'] = model.labels_

cluster_counts = df['Cluster'].value_counts()
print("Number of samples in each cluster:")
print(cluster_counts)

cluster_default_counts = df.groupby(['Cluster', 'DEFAULT']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print("\nCluster default counts (0 and 1):")
print(cluster_default_counts)

cluster_default_proportions = cluster_default_counts.div(cluster_default_counts.sum(axis=1), axis=0)*100
print("\nCluster default proportions:")
print(cluster_default_proportions)

which returns
Number of samples in each cluster:
Cluster
2    25
3    21
1    20
4    19
0    15
Name: count, dtype: int64

Cluster default counts (0 and 1):
DEFAULT   0   1
Cluster        
0         9   6
1        13   7
2        11  14
3        12   9
4        11   8

Cluster default proportions:
DEFAULT          0          1
Cluster                      
0        60.000000  40.000000
1        65.000000  35.000000
2        44.000000  56.000000
3        57.142857  42.857143
4        57.894737  42.105263


@unleasehed This is why you need to post sample data. Can you do this? Take you dataframe and write df.to_dict(). Add this to the question.

I have posted the sample data.

For the future, do not post images. Do what I instructed you to do. This come from a csv file. So, when you import it, using pd.read_csv("your_file.csv") it will have the format from you csv file. I suspect the numberical columns are as string. You need to convert them to float before doing anything df['col_x'] = df['col_x'].astype('float') or something like that.

Once you've done that, the solution should work.

i have encountered this error message : KeyError: 'col_x'

No! I wrote this as a general rule! col_x is to be replaced by you own columns.

my data are either object or int. no string.
